# Retrieve rows with dates matching the past 7 days from yesterday

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need to pull rows from one tab in a spreadsheet to another when the date is within the last 7 days from yesterday, and that matches a second criteria as well (text).

I know I can use a pivot table, but I want to automatically update a table with articles without having to manually adjust the dates in a pivot table.

I want to create a table that displays the top 20 articles by revenue (text/string) from (1) the past 30 days and (2) the past 7 days for 3 different publications.

I am pulling data from a platform that gives me rows of individual purchases with tons of columns, the ones I care about being how much revenue came from a purchase, the name of the article that the purchase came from, and the name of the publication that the article came from.

Because these rows represent individual purchases, I need to pull the articles that have the greatest sum of revenue for a specific publication. I am able to filter by publication and get the top generating articles through a pivot table. I have a table in another spreadsheet that pulls the top 20 cells in the Pivot table.

I created a pivot table, and it works, but the document to automatically pull data without me having to manually adjust the dates in the pivot table each time.

I don't know what formula to use, or how to set up the part of the formula that matches the date with any date in the last week from yesterday, so something along the lines of:

`((Today()-1)>(Today()-8))`

Comment: Use a filter, and set up a button or event macro to trigger the updating.

Comment: Try this link and then edit your question.  [Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula and replace the "A" with the text. =IF(AND(A1>TODAY()-8,D7="a"),A1,""). This will just return the value in cell A1 if it is within the past 8 days and contains certain text. I am not positive if this is what you are looking for, so let me know how else I could help.